# Rotate jpeg image

Tags: php, html

I am using the following code to rotate an uploaded jpeg image if the orientation is non-empty.

```
    if(isset($_FILES["temp_image"]))
{

    $temp_image = $this->imageupload->file_upload(TEMP_IMAGES_UPLOAD_PATH, 'temp_image');
    $path = base_url().TEMP_IMAGES_UPLOAD_DISPLAY_PATH.$temp_image;

    $exif = exif_read_data($path, "FILE,COMPUTED,ANY_TAG,IFD0,THUMBNAIL,COMMENT,EXIF", true);
        if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) 
        {
            switch($exif['Orientation']) 
            {
                case 8:
                    $temp_image = imagerotate($temp_image,90,0);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $temp_image = imagerotate($temp_image,180,0);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $temp_image = imagerotate($temp_image,-90,0);
                    break;
            }
        }
    $name = $temp_image;          
    $ilock_wb[] = array('Record'=>array('path'=>$path, 'name'=>$name));
}
```

but when I print `$exif`, I get below type array in not get "Orientation"
my output like

```
Array
(
    [FILE] => Array
        (
            [FileName] => 2848C457-0482-495A-8756-038C9B79805033997765.JPG
            [FileDateTime] => 0
            [FileSize] => 25834
            [FileType] => 2
            [MimeType] => image/jpeg
            [SectionsFound] => COMMENT
        )

    [COMPUTED] => Array
        (
            [html] => width="640" height="480"
            [Height] => 480
            [Width] => 640
            [IsColor] => 1
        )

    [COMMENT] => Array
        (
            [0] => CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 50

        )

)
```

and some images upload at time not get array. How can I solve that?

Comment: are you sure the image you're testing with actually has exif orientation data?

Comment: yes i am used exif_read_data

Comment: well, yes, but all exif fields are optional.